# i want to disable ctrl+d for my google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> shortcut in my google sheet,
I have the code but it didn't work in my google sheet.
My code is:

```
function DisableCtrld()
 {

  var Application;

  Application.OnKey ("^d", "");

 }
```

Comment: You can't```.```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in sheets but you can just bind it away with autohotkey if it is bothering you.